# Why is a Range transformed to a Vector after map operation?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Following Scala courses on Coursera, Martin Odersky showed an example code which is:

```
1 to 5 map ( i => i*i )
```

And he said the `Range` gets transformed to a `Vector` because they share the same interface (`IndexedSeq`) and the result could not be represented as a `Range`
(it was more clear in its example since he generated a pair which is not representable as a `Range`).

I'm not sure to understand because I think he said previously that in a for expression the 1st generator will determine the kind of element that will be yielded, and it seems not always true, at least for `Range`.

And I'm not sure to understand why the output is `Vector`, because `Vector` may not be the only other one implementation that can represent the result computed above.

Can someone help me understand this part please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` secretly takes a `CanBuildFrom` as an implicit argument.  Its job is to produce a new collection given the one you've already got (and the type of the contents).  Since `Range` can't contain arbitrary stuff--not even arbitrary integers--there is no `CanBuildFrom` that produces a `Range`.  The most specific supertype of `Range` that does have a `CanBuildFrom` is `IndexedSeq`.  The collection that is actually built by this is a `Vector`.

Comment: So you mean Scala implicitly imports by default some implicit CanBuildFroms and that I could eventually override them or something? Is it possible, just to understand, to produce something else than a Vector in this case?

Comment: @SebastienLorber - Indeed you can!  Look for `breakOut` as perhaps the most convenient way to do it if some other implicit already could be applicable, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592024

Comment: yes, if you explicitly provide a valid builder you can get another collection as a result

Comment: ANd what if we use a CanBuildFrom that produces something which does not provide monadic operations, can it be a problem in a for-comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure Martin also explained, `for` comprehensions correspond to (are translated into) chained invocations of the `map` and `flatMap` methods (and `foreach` if you don't use `yield`).

The reason why it generally results in a value of the type of the first generator is that `map` and `flatMap` generally return the same type as their receiver (`map` on a `List` returns a `List`, etc.).

Now the problem with `Range`s is that they cannot represent things that are not regular sequences of integers. As a consequence, the return type of `map` and `flatMap` [as defined for `Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range) cannot be `Range`. The next best match is `Vector`, the prototypical implementation of an indexed sequence.

(If you look at the source code or even the Scala doc page I linked to, you will see that it is a little more complicated that just the return type, but conceptually, that is the reason. ***Edit:*** ...and now Rex Kerr just dropped the `CanBuildFrom` bomb.)

Answer (score 1):

`Vector` is the default implementation for `IndexedSeq`. The `map` cannot be represented as a `Range` since the `Range` class is designed to contain a series of numbers that can be represented by a start, stop, and step value (similar to `range` in Python). The API docs specify that it's a special case of `IndexSeq`.

We can see `1 to 5 map { i => i * i }` will get us a container of values (1, 4, 9, 16, 25). We can get a start and stop, but no constant step value.