# scala "yield" doesn't produce the right type

Tags: scala

`yield` is mostly used in a for-yield loop to produce a new same-type collection. For example:

```
scala> val a = Array(2,3,5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 5)

scala> val result = for (elem <- a) yield 2 * elem
result: Array[Int] = Array(4, 6, 10)
```

This all works fine, the for loop takes an array and returns an array.

But then I noticed this:

```
scala> 1 to 10
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

This generates a range type collection, but when you use this in conjunction with for-yield loop, this happened:

```
scala> for (i <- (1 to 10)) yield i + 2
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

Type that comes in is range, but the type it sends out is Vector. Why is this happenning? Am I missing anything?

Comment: This is just wrong: “`yield` is mostly used in a for-yield loop to produce a new same-type collection.”

Comment: Well..that is the only case I've seen with `yield`..@Jean-PhilippePellet I assume there should be more to the meaning of `yield` and its usage

Comment: @WindDweller Much more. You use for-comprehensions for monadic flow control and composition. Take a look at how you'd use `Future` with a for-comprehension and it'll blow your mind. Also have a look at `Try` with it's ability to handle exceptions.

Comment: sort of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130458/why-is-a-range-transformed-to-a-vector-after-map-operation

Comment: @WindDweller: the second question should be moved into a separate one. although you will get similar answers, it will be less confusing.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy I will. I just didn't want to throw too many `yield` questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `Range`:

```
class Range extends AbstractSeq[Int] with IndexedSeq[Int] with CustomParallelizable[Int, ParRange] with Serializable
```

Then the signature of `map`:

```
 def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): IndexedSeq[B]
```

The reason for this is that `Range` is actually a sugared `IndexedSeq`, all it adds on top is range specific behaviour:

`Range.Inclusive`, `Range.Exclusive` etc.

The reason why `map` returns an `IndexedSeq` is likely a compiler limitation, as it cannot predict the type of the `Range` that results from the `map` operation.

Comment: Can you be more specific about `map` operation? It seems to me that the only operation I've used is "+" and it shouldn't be a `map` operation.

Comment: Haha this is interesting. I rewrote a for-loop in a `flatMap` manner and I got Vector type as well. Even in Scala-doc, `flatMap` returns `IndexedSeq`, which is a trait both `Vector` and `Range` share. It might totally be a complier limitation because it seems like when a specific sequence type is missing, `Vector` is applied in default.

Comment: What `Range` could be produced if your yield was, say, `i * 2` instead of `i + 2`? Furthermore, to make `i + 2` example produce a `Range`, it would have to get all the results and see that they were contiguous values and then build a Range for their starting and ending values.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, `Range` need not be contiguous. But they do have to have uniform interval between values (e.g., `1 to 20 by 3`), so there are still many `yield` expressions whose entire results could not be represented by a `Range`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you're not missing anything. Take a look at the signature for `map` in [Range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range).

```
 def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): IndexedSeq[B]
```

That is why it's producing the values that you see. `Range` itself "is a" `IndexedSeq`.

Why do I talk about `map` when discussing a for-comprehension? For comprehensions are syntactic sugar for compiler transformations which utilizie `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` under the hood (amongst other things.) So even if you just yield what you put in, you're calling a `map` with `identity`.

Also note, as to the `Vector` portion of why this would happen...

`IndexedSeq` is a trait. If you were to look at the source code for this trait [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/IndexedSeq.scala#L1), the companion object produces a `Vector` from the `newBuilder[A]` method:

```
object IndexedSeq extends SeqFactory[IndexedSeq] {
  override lazy val ReusableCBF  = 
      scala.collection.IndexedSeq.ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[Nothing]]
  class Impl[A](buf: ArrayBuffer[A]) extends AbstractSeq[A] with IndexedSeq[A] with Serializable {
    def length = buf.length
    def apply(idx: Int) = buf.apply(idx)
  }
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, IndexedSeq[A]] = Vector.newBuilder[A]
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, IndexedSeq[A]] =
    ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]
}
```

Comment: I was thinking if `Vector` is the "go-to" type of `IndexedSeq`, and this means whenever a `IndexSeq` is constructed, it constructs as a `Vector`. So is it true that the `flatMap` operation actually constructs something new, disregarding the fact the programmer put in a `Range` type collection?

Comment: If `flatMap` is applicable to the outcome of the for-comprehension, then yes.

Comment: @WindDweller The `flatMap` on `Range` could not return a `Range` as a result because the function you provide could do anything with the input and is not constrained to return equally spaced values, so the result cannot be statically guaranteed to be a `Range`.

Comment: You are right @TimDestan `Range` only stores a head, tail, and increment. It seems like `flatMap` will correctly return `Array`, `List`, or any other type, except `Range`

Answer (score 2):

Range has to have a fixed step between its values. Since it's impossible to infer that whatever yield returns will be a Range, the collection is made so that `map` is defined as to return an IndexedSeq, i.e. behave like an IndexedSeq which it overrides.